# Problems with pyspotify on OSX

Tags: python, spotify

I am messing around with pyspotify on a Mac, and I've been reading up on examples and documentation. I have an example application (the jukebox.py example from the pyspotify git repo) downloaded, and when I run it from the command line, I get the following:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jukebox.py", line 15, in <module>
    AudioSink = import_audio_sink()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/__init__.py", line 45, in import_audio_sink
    raise ImportError, "\n".join(error_messages)
ImportError: Tried to use spotify.audiosink.alsa.AlsaSink as audio sink, but failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/__init__.py", line 36, in import_audio_sink
    module = __import__(module, fromlist=[cls])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/alsa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import alsaaudio
ImportError: No module named alsaaudio

Tried to use spotify.audiosink.oss.OssSink as audio sink, but failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/__init__.py", line 36, in import_audio_sink
    module = __import__(module, fromlist=[cls])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/oss.py", line 1, in <module>
    import ossaudiodev
ImportError: No module named ossaudiodev

Tried to use spotify.audiosink.portaudio.PortAudioSink as audio sink, but failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/__init__.py", line 36, in import_audio_sink
    module = __import__(module, fromlist=[cls])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/portaudio.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyaudio
ImportError: No module named pyaudio

Tried to use spotify.audiosink.gstreamer.GstreamerSink as audio sink, but failed:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/__init__.py", line 36, in import_audio_sink
    module = __import__(module, fromlist=[cls])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/spotify/audiosink/gstreamer.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gobject
ImportError: No module named gobject

Was not able to import any of the audio sinks
```

I get that the python wrappers to various audio APIs/sources don't exist, but how do I know whether I need to/how to install gobject or pyaudio and their backing APIs? I tried pyaudio, but it fails, because I don't have the libraries it wraps around (I think). Has anyone gotten this before? Thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this? I'm struggling with the same?

Answer (score 0):

This works for the `master` branch `jukebox.py` (as of 2013-04-13 [7eb1c53](https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify/blob/7eb1c53b4ff55e726b168ddd93b652e17d331fd9/examples/jukebox.py))

```
brew install portaudio

pip install pyaudio

python -c "import pyaudio"
```

And then:

```
python example-jukebox-master.py -u myuser -p mypassword
Logging in, please wait...
Logged in!
jukebox> help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
list  ls

Undocumented commands:
======================
EOF               browse  next   queue            search  toplist
add_new_playlist  help    pause  quit             shell   unwatch
add_to_playlist   logout  play   remove_playlist  stop    watch

> help ls
 List the playlists, or the contents of a playlist
```

And this from the current develop:

```
python example-jukebox.py -u myuser -p mypassword -a portaudio
```